# How can I print the first digit of an int?

Tags: java

```
public class ldigit
{
     public static void main( String args[])
     { 
        int a;
        int lastdigit;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        a = n;     
        while( n>10 )
        {
            a = a / 10;          
        }
        lastdigit = n % 10;

        System.out.println("firstdigit" + a );
        System.out.println("last digit" + lastdigit);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing ..but whats the issue ??

Comment: You should definitely read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming the Question Not Asked is "why doesn't this code work".

You may end up with a value of '10' in `a`. Change your `while` line to

```
while( a>=10 )
```

to make it work.

Comment: +1 for spotting another bug.

Comment: Actually, no solution posted so far works for negative numbers.

Comment: The OP never mentioned negative numbers. But it's as simple as adding "if (a < 0) a = -a;" before the while.

Comment: The OP never mentioned positive numbers either. The question was about the first digit of an int and an int is signed. Also, your fix won't work for Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: Excellent point. So for negative numbers, it'd need a different "while" loop, and only after that change the sign.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (n > 10) {
    a = a / 10;          
}
```

You have an infinite loop here, since you never modify `n` inside the loop.

I don't see any reason to have two variables `a` and `n`.

Side note: look how the code is much clearer and readable now that Maroun Maroun formatted it. Strive to format your code in a perfect way. You'll spend hours looking at code: you'd better make it easy to read.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that :D

Answer (score 0):

Hey your While Loop is wrong do it like This

```
while(a>10)
{
    a=a/10;
 }
  firsdigit=a;
  lastdigit=n%10;
```